# How to display all numbers in US format with commas?

Tags: jquery, spring

I'm using spring. I want to display all the numbers on my site in US format.

Eg: 1000000000 should be displayed as 1,000,000,000.

Is there any jquery available for doing this? os any other method? thanks.

Comment: Spring is Java, and Java has java.text.NumberFormat classes.  See if that'll do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JSP as the Spring view technology, you can use the `formatNumber` tag in order to display a number based on the locale:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<fmt:formatNumber type="number" value="1000000" />
```

If you want to make sure that the US locale is used, add this before the `formatNumber` tag:

```
<fmt:setLocale value="en_US"/>
```

You shouldn't use jQuery for this, it will only slow your web page down unnecessarily. It is better to send the number already formatted to the client, than doing the formatting by running a script on the web browser.

Comment: `<fmt:formatNumber>` will format according to the current locale of the request. Nothing guarantees that it will the US locale.

Comment: @pap If you don't pass it another parameter yes. Of course it can be customized.